# Delete all virtualenv and start from scratch

Tags: python, virtualenv, homebrew

I used to use macport and recently switch to homebrew. After cleaning up all the macports enviornments using python version installed by homebrew I did pip install virtualenv.

```
$virtualenv test --no-site-packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.9.1
```

I also check what virtualenv are available in the system, it was bit confusing to see

```
$virtualenv
virtualenv      virtualenv-2.6
```

SO I uninstall what I installed and then tried to do a reinstall:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I checked how the structure looks like in /usr/local/bin: I don't think any of these virtualenv(s) are symlinks:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel       276 Mar 12  2013 virtualenv
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel       284 Mar 12  2013 virtualenv-2.6
```

How can I delete all virtualenv, and start from scratch?

Comment: Are you sure that `virtualenv` is not actually a symlink to `virtualenv-2.6`?

Comment: I just checked it i don't think so I did which virtualenv
`$which virtualenv`
`/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

`-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel       276 Mar 12  2013 virtualenv`
`-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel       284 Mar 12  2013 virtualenv-2.6`

Comment: What does `stat /usr/local/bin/virtualenv` say?

Comment: `$stat /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
16777218 302855061 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 0 276 "Oct 13 12:19:26 2013" "Mar 12 16:49:07 2013" "Mar 31 08:57:36 2013" "Mar 12 16:49:07 2013" 4096 8 0 /usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo based on the date of the virtualenv it looks like for sure the oldstuff still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling everything and removing all the virtualenv, I was able to successfully install. Just incase if you have

```
~/.pydistutils.cfg
```

You might want to follow instructions in: 
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12667#issuecomment-6257342