# Can't pip install virtualenv on Mac 10.9 Mavericks with brewed python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, virtualenv, homebrew

I am trying to setup `virtualenv` to keep my python `env` clean and organized. 
Well, actually I'm trying to install `scrapy` as I wrote about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106687/trouble-installing-scrapy-on-10-9-mavericks) which opened this can of python worms that I'm now trying cleanup after will `virtualenv`.

The final verdict was to install `virtualenv` (which is failing) and hence this post. This is where I'm at:

```
$ virtualenv test
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

I understand that this means wherever `virtualenv` installed via `pip install virtualenv` isn't in my path but it should be after following these:

1. [Can't pip install virtualenv in OS X 10.8 with brewed python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860971/cant-pip-install-virtualenv-in-os-x-10-8-with-brewed-python-2-7)
2. http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/
3. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/12667#issuecomment-6257342
4. http://www.lowindata.com/2013/installing-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/
5. [Delete all virtualenv and start from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348077/delete-all-virtualenv-and-start-from-scratch)

`brew doctor` returns `ready to brew`.

My guess is that my system python and my brew python aren't playing nicely but I'm out of ideas as to what else I can do to fix this.

At this point I'm willing to do a clean install of just about everything (even mac os x) if that's what it takes. I'm pretty sure I `sudo pip install`'d something(s) a while ago and I'm paying the price for it now.

More details of the install:

```
~ ∮ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
~ ∮ pip install virtualenvwrapper
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Cleaning up...
```

I tried both 
`brew install python --with-brewed-openssl` AND `brew install python --framework` (after uninstalling the previous when it wasn't working) (and all the other suggestions in the above links)

thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the result if you type `which virtualenv`

Comment: @Ben returns empty. 
however, in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` there exists virtualenv, virtualenv_clone and virtualenvwrapper files.

Comment: This leads me to think its installing ok, but is a path issue. However, I know `brew doctor` checks these paths as I've seen comments about needing or not needing certain paths in my PATH variable. I made the suggested changes and now brew seems content with this setup.

Comment: My `which virtualenv` returns `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` - Mac 10.9 with homebrew python. I guess try a `pip uninstall` on virtualenv and then reinstall again with pip, see if it puts it in the same place...

Comment: this works! Although I don't really understand why. On the homebrew python page they explain where & why python modules will be saved in /site-packages https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python#site-packages-and-the-pythonpath 
I'm going to see if this fixes my scrapy issue (linked at the beginning of this post) as well.

Comment: Great, I'll submit it as an answer then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`virtualenv` looks to be in the wrong place. On Mac 10.9 it should be in `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`.

Try a `pip uninstall` on virtualenv and then reinstall again with pip, see if it puts it in the right location.

Comment: this works, although I'd still like to know why it was broken in the first place and how this fixed it. according to the homebrew python github page pip is suppose to install things in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which is where it was. there are two issues in my head, 1) `virtualenv` was in `/site-packages` so why wasn't it working and 2) when I pip reinstalled it, why did it put it somewhere other than where it said it would install modules: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python#site-packages-and-the-pythonpath (edit for correct link)

Comment: Agreed, I'd be interested in knowing too (I had the same problem). Does this file exist for you: `~/.pydistutils.cfg` / what's in it?

Comment: `~/.pydistutils.cfg` does not exist for me.

Comment: I confess that I wouldn't have reinstalled virtualenv if there were no upvotes on this answer already. Good thing I did and I am too, clueless about why this worked. Alls well that ends well.